# How to read s3 image response as object

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, django-views

I'm getting the `ValueError: embedded null byte` while trying to convert the s3 response to b64data

I tried it with `urllib.request` package same `ValueError: embedded null byte` is thrown

```py
s3_response_object = settings.S3_CLIENT.get_object(Bucket=settings.BUCKET_NAME, Key='image_name.png')
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()
with open(object_content, 'rb') as img:
    b64_image = base64.b64encode(img.read())
```

Here is the other code tried with presigned URL

```py
signed_uri = settings.S3_CLIENT. \
generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                       Params={'Bucket':settings.BUCKET_NAME,
                       'Key': 'image_name.png'})
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(signed_uri).read()
with open(contents, "rb") as image_file:
    b64_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

both method throws this error

```
    with open(object_content, 'rb') as img:
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

But using the pre-signed URI I can open the image but the image is needed as b64data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to call .read() twice. 
type of object_content is byte

Do something like:

```
signed_uri = settings.S3_CLIENT. \
generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                   Params={'Bucket':settings.BUCKET_NAME,
                   'Key': 'image_name.png'})
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(signed_uri).read()
b64_img = base64.b64encode(contents)
```